# Pythonic way to reuse code blocks in functions

Tags: python, function, local-variables

Is there a clean way to reuse code blocks in python classes to avoid having to retype the same code? For example lets say at the beginning of 2 different functions there is the same lines of code required to set up the function (where it is desired to keep the set up variables locally in the function).

```
def func1(path, x, y):
    img = load_img('path')
    img.normalize()
    foo = Foo(x)
    bar = Bar(y)

    **rest of the function (using img, foo and bar)

def func2(path, x, y):
    img = load_img('path')
    img.normalize()
    foo = Foo(x)
    bar = Bar(y)

    **different code here to func 1
```

Is there a standard best practice to set up the local variables to avoid code repetition? Like a function which can set local variables (maybe using nonlocal)? I know I could technically do the entire set up in a single function, however with a lot of input and output variables it might get a bit messy. I just wanted to see if there was a more elegant way to approach this, as ideally I'd just be able to call some arbitrary function which sets up the entire local space.

*Also just noting, I am aware I can wrap all the code in a class, turn the functions into methods and have shared attributes, however I don't think that's quite the right solution for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the common code in another function that returns the values.

```
def common(path, x, y):
    img = load_img(path)
    img.normalize
    return img, Foo(x), Bar(y)

def func1(path, x, y):
    img, foo, bar = common(path, x, y)

    # different code

def func2(path, x, y):
    img, foo, bar = common(path, x, y)

    # different code
```

You might also consider using a decorator.